# Using ngx-datatable, I need to find the next and previous row in the table

Tags: ngx-datatable

ngx-datatable doesn't seem to provide a way to know the next or previous record. It only multi-sorts visually. I've tried recreating the sort separately by matching the [sorts] array, but the table can still be in an unknown order. I tried forcing a hidden sort field at the end of the sort array for a predicable order, but changing the sort array in the onSortChange event doesn't force a resort. I need to find either the next/prev record, or a way to trigger a resort when a make a programmatic change.

Comment: I'm far from an expert, but perhaps you could add a key that you can sort on.

Comment: I added a hidden column that I could append to the end of the sort list to force a known order. However, capturing the sorts list and appending the sort column list in the onChange equivalent does not trigger a resort. clicking a new sort in the header is then appending after my hidden sort, preventing the desired sort.